# How do I give jmxterm access to sun.tools.jconsole.LocalVirtualMachine in Java 17?

Tags: java, jmx, java-module, java-17, illegalaccessexception

I am trying to use [jmxterm](https://github.com/jiaqi/jmxterm) with [Eclipse Temurin Java 17](https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/?version=17), but because of the module encapsulation changes in Java 17, jmxterm no longer has access to the class [`sun.tools.jconsole.LocalVirtualMachine`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/jdk.jconsole/share/classes/sun/tools/jconsole/LocalVirtualMachine.java) in the `jdk.jconsole` module. So, running the following command:

```
printf "open  25522\n" | java -jar jmxterm-1.0.4-uber.jar -v verbose
```

outputs the following exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy6.getAllVirtualMachines(Unknown Source)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.jdk6.Jdk6JavaProcessManager.get(Jdk6JavaProcessManager.java:28)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.SyntaxUtils.getUrl(SyntaxUtils.java:41)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.cmd.OpenCommand.execute(OpenCommand.java:64)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.cc.CommandCenter.doExecute(CommandCenter.java:161)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.cc.CommandCenter.doExecute(CommandCenter.java:134)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.cc.CommandCenter.execute(CommandCenter.java:176)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.boot.CliMain.execute(CliMain.java:149)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.boot.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.utils.WeakCastUtils$2 cannot access class sun.tools.jconsole.LocalVirtualMachine (in module jdk.jconsole) because module jdk.jconsole does not export sun.tools.jconsole to unnamed module @3bb50eaa
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:560)
        at org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.utils.WeakCastUtils$2.invoke(WeakCastUtils.java:136)
        ... 9 more
```

To fix this, I thought I would have to recompile jmxterm with the `--add-exports` option, so to do that, I added this plugin to the [pom.xml](https://github.com/jiaqi/jmxterm/blob/main/pom.xml):

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>17</target>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-exports</arg>
            <arg>jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

and I also had to add this config to the surefire plugin:

```xml
          <argLine>
              --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
              --add-opens java.management/javax.management.openmbean=ALL-UNNAMED
          </argLine>
```

I have verified that Maven is using the correct JDK to build jmxterm:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 17.0.4.1, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

So with these changes I was able to build a new jmxterm uber jar with `mvn package`.

I then tried to run my new jmxterm jar with `--add-exports` using this command:

```
printf "open  25522\n" | java -jar jmxterm/target/jmxterm-1.0.4-uber.jar --add-exports jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole=ALL-UNNAMED -v verbose
```

but it still threw the same exception as above.

Other things I have tried that also didn't work:

- Using `--add-opens` instead of `--add-exports` in the `java` command even though I don't think that should be necessary
- Setting the `source` to 17 in `pom.xml`
- Adding `--add-modules jdk.jconsole` argument to the `java` command as well as to `pom.xml`

Is there something I am missing or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the command:

```
printf "open  25522\n" | java -jar jmxterm/target/jmxterm-1.0.4-uber.jar --add-exports jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole=ALL-UNNAMED -v verbose
```

You are passing the `--add-exports` flag as a program argument, rather than a VM argument.

The flag should be passed before the `-jar` flag instead:

```
printf "open  25522\n" | java --add-exports jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole=ALL-UNNAMED -jar jmxterm/target/jmxterm-1.0.4-uber.jar -v verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid specifying `--add-exports` on the command line each time by adding it in the manifest of the JAR file:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        …
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.boot.CliMain</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <Add-Exports>jdk.jconsole/sun.tools.jconsole</Add-Exports>
        </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</plugin>
```

Note that this will only work when you run the JAR with `java -jar jmxterm.jar` and won't with other commands, e.g. `java -cp jmxterm.jar org.cyclopsgroup.jmxterm.boot.CliMain`.

*See also*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75634087