# Does a way exist through jar, manifest... to setup --add-exports, --add-opens directives definitively, to avoid passing them on command line?

Tags: java, bash, maven, apache-spark, java-17

I encounter a problem that the whole *Spark* community has:
when I switch from *Java* 11 to 17, *Spark* (for me the `3.3.2` version) fails with:

`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0xe25b2fe) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0xe25b2fe`

The solution is to :

- Change your *Maven* launch of unit tests,
- Change your Dockerfiles,
- Change your *java* command lines in any script involving directly or indirectly your classes or *Spark*,
- And ask all your customers to do the same

to go from:

```bash
java -jar target/myProgram.jar
```

to :

```bash
java --add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED \
   --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED \
   -jar myProgram.jar
```

And you understand that the response is, at 100%:
"*No, let's stay on Java 11.

Spark (or Scala) doesn't handle Java 17 correctly, making it unusable with it*"

Does an alternative solution exist, that would allow me to, like I would do savagely a:
`System.setProperty("my.property", "myValue")`
if I was really willing so,

to setup at the earliest place of my build process,
something that would ensure that for/from any launch of the classes, jars I'm producing here - whenever they are intended for tests, runtime, containerization... -,

the underlying *java* command launching them will assume the
`--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED    --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED`
to come along with it, avoiding for anyone the clumsy (and sometimes impossible task) of correcting all the java command lines everywhere?

Because it's a definitive stumbling block for the migration from Java 11 to Java 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JEP 261: Module System](https://openjdk.org/jeps/261) has this to say:

> Two new **JDK-specific** *[emphasis added]* JAR-file manifest attributes are defined to correspond to the `--add-exports` and `--add-opens` command-line options:
>
> - `Add-Exports: <module>/<package>( <module>/<package>)*`
> - `Add-Opens: <module>/<package>( <module>/<package>)*`
>
> The value of each attribute is a space-separated list of slash-separated module-name/package-name pairs. A `<module>/<package>` pair in the value of an `Add-Exports` attribute has the same meaning as the command-line option `--add-exports <module>/<package>=ALL-UNNAMED`. A `<module>/<package>` pair in the value of an `Add-Opens` attribute has the same meaning as the command-line option `--add-opens <module>/<package>=ALL-UNNAMED`.
>
> Each attribute can occur at most once, in the main section of a `MANIFEST.MF` file. A particular pair can be listed more than once. If a specified module was not resolved, or if a specified package does not exist, then the corresponding pair is ignored. **These attributes are interpreted only in the main executable JAR file of an application, i.e., in the JAR file specified to the `-jar` option of the Java run-time launcher; they are ignored in all other JAR files.** *[emphasis added]*

As emphasized, these attributes are JDK-specific. They do not appear to be part of the [JAR file specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/jar/jar.html). And they only work with the JAR file specified with the `-jar` option.

Comment: Well, we only have to hope that they will succeed in correcting what causes this trouble in either Spark or Scala. Until then, our program will stay linked to the previous Java version. In my mind, in the past, migrating from Java 3 to 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 was easier. Since 9+, it takes up to years.

Comment: The access to `sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer` most likely is for releasing the buffer timely, instead of relying on garbage collection. A clean solution is not possible yet; it will be there when the [Foreign memory access API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/package-summary.html) is not  a *preview feature* anymore.